# Couldn't able to send file(docx) using PHPMailer

Tags: php, email

```
$mail->Subject = "$email : $subject";
$mail->Body = "$message";
$mail->AddAddress("someMail@somedomain.com");
//$absolutePath = "resumes"
//$mail->AddAttachment($absolutePath , $name = 'Resume.docx', $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/octet-stream' );
$mail -> AddAttachment("resumes/resume.docx");
if(!$mail->Send()){
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else{
    echo "Message has been sent";
}
```

I m getting the mail with everything but not getting attachment with it.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: You are using a relative path for your attachment. The script may not be reading the file.

Comment: Plus, when dealing with files, make sure your form contains a valid enctype and using a POST method.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Still not getting anything. Please be more specific.

Comment: time to use `var_dump()` then, see what's passing through or not. I have to run.

Comment: try $mail -> AddAttachment( "PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE" , "resume.docx");